# gwt error when try add IsSerializable in enum

Tags: gwt, gwt-rpc

Hello i try Serialize my enum class but i have got error when i try compile my project.

this is my simple enum :

```
import com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.IsSerializable;

public enum ConversationType implements IsSerializable {

    PAIR, GROUP, ALL;

    ConversationType() {

    }

}
```

i also have got gwt-user in my pom dependencies:

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
      <artifactId>gwt-user</artifactId>
      <version>2.5.0</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

In that project i have got other DTO object and that object implement IsSerializable. 
When i delete IsSerializable from that enum everything is fine.

This is my error:

```
An exception has occurred in the compiler (1.7.0_13). Please file a bug at the Java Developer Connection (http://java.sun.com/webapps/bugreport)  after checking the Bug Parade for duplicates. Include your program and the following diagnostic in your report.  Thank you.
com.sun.tools.javac.code.Symbol$CompletionFailure: class file for com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.IsSerializable not found
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All enums are serializable by GWT-RPC, so why are you trying to make it implement `IsSerializable` if that triggers a bug in `javac`?

Reference: https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideServerCommunication#DevGuideSerializableTypes